# How can I match a string with only Chinese letters using a regex?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, boost, unicode

I want to get a regex which can only match a string consisted of Chinese character and without English or any other character. [\u4e00-\u9fa5] doesn't work at all, and [^x00-xff] would match the situation with punctuate or other language character.

```
boost::wregex reg(L"\\w*");
bool b = boost::regex_match(L"我a", reg);    // expected to be false
b = boost::regex_match(L"我,", reg);         // expected to be false
b = boost::regex_match(L"我", reg);          // expected to be true
```

Comment: @NicolBolas: The question is about `boost::regex`, not C++11 `std::regex`.

Comment: @MSalters: Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex works fine.

```
boost::wregex reg(L"^[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+");
```

Answer (score 3):

Boost with ICU [can use character classes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html). I think you're looking for `\p{Han}` script. Alternatively, U+4E00..U+9FFF is `\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}`